# ActiveRecord banchmark in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm looking at console of with working rails application.
Every request/response finished with next line

```
Completed 200 OK in 1169ms (Views: 74.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The problem is that ActiveRecord always show 0.0 and it's wrong, how to fix this ?

Comment: Is this in production with caching enabled, by any chance?

Comment: it's in development mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rails logging is not very precise. you might want to have a look at time_bandits for more detailed info: https://github.com/skaes/time_bandits